# How to update multiple nodes in the local graph with one mutation result

Tags: relayjs

Lets say there is a mutation which updates **more than one** node serverside.

What is the preferred way to let Relay update the nodes in the local store?

In other words:

Is it possible to return a list of updated nodes and tell Relay to apply some kind of FIELDS_CHANGE for every returned node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to update multiple nodes and to have Relay update its client store accordingly. There are two cases:

### 1) Updated nodes belong to the same parent:

Each of the changed nodes does not need to be updated individually with `FIELDS_CHANGE` mutator configuration. We just need to update the parent of those nodes with `FIELDS_CHANGE`. The child fields, which should be fetched and updated, are specified in the fat query.

A good example is `MarkAllTodosMutation` of Relay's todo example, where `viewer` is parent of `todos` connection type (`todo` nodes). Since this mutation changes multiple nodes under `viewer`, in the [`getConfig()`](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/80e91364f6be6a5ae4e9122383a1d8eaa5918236/examples/todo/js/mutations/MarkAllTodosMutation.js#L48-L55) function, we specify that `viewer` should be updated:

```
getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
    fieldIDs: {
      viewer: this.props.viewer.id,
    },
  }];
}
```

In the [`getFatQuery()`](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/80e91364f6be6a5ae4e9122383a1d8eaa5918236/examples/todo/js/mutations/MarkAllTodosMutation.js#L38-L47) function, we specify `todos` and `completedCount` fields of `viewer` should be fetched and updated in the store. The fields of `todo` to be updated in the store are specified in `fragments` or in the fat query.

```
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on MarkAllTodosPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
      viewer {
        completedCount,
        todos,
      },
    }
  `;
}
```

### 2) Updated nodes belong to different parents:

On the client-side mutation, the nodes to be updated are passed as props to the mutation. In the `getConfig()` function, each node needs to be configured with `FIELDS_CHANGE`. `getFatQuery` function specifies which fields of the changed nodes should be updated in the store. Ideally, it should have all the fields which can be affected by that mutation.